# WinRT - Start an application on Windows boot?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm working on a Metro style application in the new WinRT (.NET 4.5) framework for Windows 8, and I was wondering if it would be possible somehow for an application (through the registry or some other means) to register itself to start up when Windows starts as well.

I haven't been able to find anything about this anywhere else, only for Windows 7 or below, with normal-style applications.

Comment: You mean microsoft disables all the common approaches for applications to start on boot and redid the windows service model? I dont think so - back to readin the windows programming documentation, page one onward. There are a couple of ways to autoamtically start applications when a user logs on or the system boots.

Comment: @TomTom: WinRT is a different API from Win32. The question is whether you can control these things from WinRT, not how you can do it from a generic Windows app. :)

Comment: WinRT is not the kernel, though - the standard API is still there. How you think for example SQL Server will run ioon Server 8? The new UI is just that - sitting on top of the old stuff.

Comment: @TomTom: No it isn't. Not if you're planning to run on an ARM CPU, or on a tablet. It's there on a traditional x86 desktop Windows machine, but if you plan to use WinRT it might be to allow your app to run on platforms where Win32 is not available. (The kernel has nothing to do with it btw. Win32 isn't the kernel either)

Comment: @jalf: What makes you think there's no Win32 API on Windows ARM?

Comment: What sort of application are you making such that a user would want it to run when the boot up (although presumably you mean log in)?

Comment: +1 WinRT is a different API from Win32. That's the key detail here. Not how can you workaround WinRT, but how do you do it from WinRT

Comment: @Gabe - A customized inventory management system. Or scheduling. Or any type of thing where its a business tool and has one purpose. I assume the attempt is to leverage COTS hardware and tools.

Comment: @RitchMelton: Those types of apps are things I would write as WinRT desktop apps.

Comment: @Gabe - I wrote bingo scheduling software at one very sad point in my career. We had to use colors instead of words on buttons, because so many of the volunteer helpers couldn't read/or process the words. That's the kind of person who needs to be locked out of everything else. FWIW, A support call would go something like, 'Did you red-green-green-red-green-blue?'

Comment: @Gabe: how about Microsoft's statement that there will be zero backwards compatibility? I assume they know what they're talking about.

Comment: @jalf: Have you seen a direct statement from MS that Windows 8 on ARM will not have any Win32 APIs? I have heard there will not be any *x86 compatibility*, but I find it hard to believe that every program that MS intends to run on Windows ARM (like IE and Office) will be rewritten to use only WinRT just so that they can avoid making Win32 available!

Comment: @Gabe: That's how I understood their statement. I could be wrong. But keep in mind that Microsoft definitely *wants* applications to be rewritten for the primary ARM target (tablets). They want to force you to use Metro there, and they want to avoid hastily ported Win32 apps on their shiny new platform.  They are not going to port IE or Office as-is to ARM, because those *need* to be rewritten to work well on a touch-based platform.

Comment: @jalf: Indeed, you are correct that MS wants you to rewrite your app for use on a tablet; and they are rewriting IE for it. That "rewrite" of IE is called IE 10. While the Metro version of IE 10 may have a new UI and not allow plug-ins, the core of IE 10 has to use Win32 or it wouldn't run on Win7.

Comment: @Gabe: that is assuming it's the same code used for both versions. :) Perhaps you should take a look at WP7, which does not allow you to access the Win32 API (not without a lot of unsupported trickery, anyway), and yet it still has a version of IE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to make a Metro style application launch at boot.  The user will have to invoke the application from the start screen.  Metro style applications cannot be services and so launching them at boot time doesn't seem like the right approach any more than launching Microsoft Word or Adobe Photoshop at boot time would be.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's goal with Metro-style apps is that the user is always in control. Therefore, Metro-style apps cannot activate themselves when a machine boots up. Furthermore, traditional Win32/.NET desktop code cannot interact with Metro-style apps and so cannot start a Metro-style app behind the scenes.

That said, if your app has registered itself as the handler for the rendering of its own tile, then it gets called periodically and is asked to re-render its tile's content so it should always be able to show its latest status/news/info to the user when they view their start page.

Comment: how exactly do you do this: "That said, if your app has registered itself as the handler for the rendering of its own tile, then it gets called periodically and is asked to re-render its tile's content"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have all your star tup stuff running as a service that exposes the appropriate WinRT level connectivity. Then the user only needs to fir up the client app.

Goo separation too.